# What is the equivalent to returning NULL in vectors in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, null

One of the ways to return a 'NULL' vector is by returning an empty vector but are then other alternatives for me to modify my code such that I am able to tell that a vector has no solution.

```
vector<int> howSum(vector<int> arr,int val ){
    if (val==0) return {};
    if (val<0) return NULL;
    vector<int> res = {};
    for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
        vector<int> temp = howSum(arr,val-arr[i]);
        if (temp.empty()) return res;
        else if (temp[0]!=0){
            res.insert(res.begin(),temp.begin(),temp.end());
            return res;
        }
    }
    return {};

}
'''
```

Comment: It could be `std::optional<std::vector<int>>`  but what is wrong with empty vector?

Comment: So and an empty vector is a solution, and you want to be able to differentiate the empty vector form no solution for which you want to return `nullptr`? To decide what you should do there depends on whether no solution should be considered as an error or not.

Comment: There are other questions like. Is it even valid that `val` is negative (`if (val<0) return NULL`)  or should `vector<int> howSum(vector<int> arr,int val )` be `vector<int> howSum(vector<int> arr, unsigned int val )`, and if so shouldn't there be a check at `vector<int> temp = howSum(arr,val-arr[i]);` if  `val-arr[i]` is smaller then `0`?

Comment: Another option would be `std::variant<std::vector<int>, nullptr_t>`, but `std::optional` would be cleaner.  Or, you could simply `throw` an exception if there is no solution.

Comment: No solution is not considered an error but it is sort of backtracking? When a solution is not found, I will be able to differentiate it from an empty array which is a solution.